# String vs long performance in Java

Tags: java, string, performance, comparison, long-integer

As I read in another questions, int has a much better performance than a long, and a little better performance than a string.

Let's say that I have a number greater than an int and I want to use it for comparisons with similar numbers: What type of variable has better performance for such a case? long or string?

For example to compare 111.222.333.444 with 555.666.777.888:

```
long x = 111222333444;
long y = 555666777888;
if(x == y){ /*code*/ }
```

VS

```
string x = "111222333444";
string y = "555666777888";
if(x.equals(y)){ /*code*/ }
```

Which case has the best performance? The difference is significant?

Comment: When it comes to questions about performance, the only real answer is to test it.

Comment: And if you're going to test it, be sure to use a good microbenchmarking tool (like, for example [JMH](http://java-performance.info/jmh/)--although there are lots of other good tools out there as well). Note also that these tests are not equivalent. Leading zeroes in the string will yield different results: 1 vs "01", for example.

Comment: The difference between into and long is almost negligible. You might see a difference on 32-bit platfirms, but, then again, given the overhead of the JVM and JIT code, in general, not worth getting all spun up about.

Comment: String is a sequence of bytes vs a single 32-bit or 64-bit quantity. int and long comparisons should always compare more efficiently than comparing a sequence of bytes or words.

Comment: numerical or boolean data-types are always lot more faster than other user defined data types (including String). However, char data type is also very faster, because it stores int value and returns equivalent ASCII character of that number.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> As I read in another questions, int has a much better performance than a long ...

Well what you have read is probably wrong.  Or more likely, what you have *understood* from what you have read is wrong.

It is true that on some machines an arithmetic operations on a `long` *may* take longer than an analogous `int` operation.  But on a modern machine, there is likely to be no difference (for the arithmetic itself), and even when there is a difference it will be just 1 or 2 clock cycles; i.e. nano-seconds.

So "a lot better" is an exaggeration.

> ...  and a little better performance than a string.

That is wrong too.  In fact, operations on `int` values is going to be a LOT faster than operations on `String` object.  For instance, consider

```
String x = "111222333444";
String y = "555666777888";
if (x.equals(y)) { /*code*/ }
```

The `equals` method will do the following:

1. Test if `x == y` and return `true` if it is.
2. Test if `y` is a String, and return `false` if it isn't.
3. Test that the lengths of the 2 strings are the same and return `false` if they aren't.
4. Loop over the characters in the string, comparing the characters at the same position, and returning `false` if they aren't equal.
5. Return `true` if the loop finishes without finding non-equal characters.

Plus the overhead of a method call (that is too large to inline).

We are talking about (I estimate) a minimum of 20 to 30 machine instructions, and many more if the two strings are equal, or equal at the start.

By contrast, `x == y` using `int` or `long` is just one instruction<sup>1</sup>.

---

However, there is a bigger point here.

The chances are that you are actually wasting your time here.  Unless you are doing these operations for *millions* of numbers, the chances are that the difference in performance is not going to be noticeable.

My advice is:

- Don't optimize unless you have to.
- Don't even *think* about this kind of thing unless you have to.
- If you do have to (i.e. you have real, hard performance numbers to say that your code is too slow), then do it scientifically.  Write some benchmarks involving running your >>real<< code on >>real<< data, and use a profile to figure out where the code is actually spending most of its time.  Then optimize only those parts of the code.

---

<sup>1 - I'm no expert on instruction level performance, but [this document](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) seems to be saying that an Intel `CMP` instruction takes 1, 2 or 3 clock cycles.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

The long is going to be faster -- and on 64-bit platforms, it'll be about as fast as an int. But unless this is in a very tight loop, it's probably not going to make any significant difference for your app overall. The first rule of micro-optimizations is: don't.

I wrote up a quick JMH benchmark to test int, long, and String comparisons, and here are the results on my laptop:

```
EqualityComparisons.cInt     avgt  100  0.004 ±  0.001  us/op
EqualityComparisons.cLong    avgt  100  0.006 ±  0.001  us/op
EqualityComparisons.cString  avgt  100  0.011 ±  0.001  us/op
```

The relevant bit of the benchmark was:

```
@Setup
public void setup() {
  one = (int) System.nanoTime();
  two = QuickRand.next(one);
  oneS = String.format("%11d", one);
  twoS = String.format("%11d", two);
  oneL = one;
  twoL = two;
}

@Benchmark
public boolean cInt() { return one == two; }

@Benchmark
public boolean cLong() { return oneL == twoL; }

@Benchmark
public boolean cString() { return oneS.equals(twoS); }
```

A few things to note:

- long and int are both about as fast -- within the margin of error
- Strings are about 2.75x slower
- even those slow Strings take about 0.011 microseconds per comparison, which means you can do about 100 million of them a second. In other words, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I'm dubious of any benchmark that (apparently) says it takes .04 to .06 microseconds per `int` or `long` comparison.

Comment: @StephenC Fwiw, my benchmarks show about .004 - .006 microseconds -- I think you misread and dropped a zero (I also mistyped it for the String bit in my bullet points -- will edit.)

Comment: I was extrapolating from your `String` number in your bullet points.  But even so, the factor of 2.75 is about an order of magnitude different to my intuition.  I would have thought the difference was much greater.

Comment: @StephenC Me too, to be honest. I dunno, branch prediction and other optimizations? I'm not a JMH expert, but I posted the benchmark, so I welcome any actionable feedback.

Comment: @StephenC One issue in my benchmark is that it the comparisons always have the same results -- returning true. I'll re-run it in a bit with a modified benchmark, where some comparisons return true and others return false.

Comment: @StephenC I re-ran the benchmark, parameterized such that sometimes the two numbers/ints are equal, and that sometimes they're not. I also ran the benchmark for longer, and while the numbers all came down a bit, the ratios were about the same as above. The ratios actually got a bit closer when the numbers were unequal (which makes sense, since determining inequality can be short-circuited with strings, meaning that they're better -- that is, comparatively less-worse).